# System.Threading.Mutex AbandonMutexException reason in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Imagine this code:

```
public class Kitchen(){
    private readonly Mutex kitchenLock = new Mutex(true, "Kitchen");
    private readonly object _lock = new Object();

    public void Enter(){
        lock(_lock){
           kitchenLock.WaitOne(-1); //wait indefinitely 
        }
    }

    public void DoCooking(){
        //cook stuff...
    }

    public void Leave(){
        lock(_lock){
           kitchenLock.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

On my function bellow, called by a zillion of different and bad behaved threads i do this:

```
Kitchen kit = new Kitchen();

kit.Enter();

kit.DoCooking();

kit.Leave();
```

Everything is fine in the code above. But the kit.Leave() throws a AbandonMutexException, why is that? Can find an answer... I muted the exception and it works fine. Is it a safe guard of .NET?

Comment: The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a nice explanation with an example program. There they were triggering it by using the mutex manually - perhaps similar to what would happen if Enter was called without Leave and something else tried to grab the mutex? At any rate, do you have any sort of protection if Leave fails to be called correctly, perhaps some sort of an IDisposable pattern?

Comment: @JTrana The question had a bug, Closes should had been Leave, it a typing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone that tried to answer my question, but I've found the answer myself.

Besides the comments regarding bugs, there is no bug in this code :) (sorry), instead there is a misunderstand of the meaning of initiallyOwned parameter when instantiating the kitchen mutex.

Mutex MSDN documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and says:

```
Initializes a new instance of the Mutex class with a Boolean value that indicates whether the 
calling thread should have initial ownership of the mutex, and a string that is the name of the 
mutex.
```

But at the beginning that didn't make much sense, so I thought yes the creating thread should own the mutex, why not? don't even know what this means, but sound good!

Although after seeing all MSDN examples regarding this I understood what it means to be initiallyOwned, initiallyOwned means that the thread that creates mutex has an implicit call to the mutex WaitOne method, meaning, obviously, that the thread Initially OWNS IT!

Here is an MSDN example:

```
// Create a new Mutex. The creating thread owns the 
// Mutex. 
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex(true);
private const int numIterations = 1;
private const int numThreads = 3;

static void Main()
{
    // Create the threads that will use the protected resource. 
    for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
        myThread.Name = String.Format("Thread{0}", i + 1);
        myThread.Start();
    }

    // Wait one second before allowing other threads to 
    // acquire the Mutex.
    Console.WriteLine("Creating thread owns the Mutex.");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Creating thread releases the Mutex.\r\n");
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}

private static void MyThreadProc()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        UseResource();
    }
}

// This method represents a resource that must be synchronized 
// so that only one thread at a time can enter. 
private static void UseResource()
{
    // Wait until it is safe to enter.
    mut.WaitOne();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} has entered the protected area", 
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

    // Place code to access non-reentrant resources here. 

    // Simulate some work.
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} is leaving the protected area\r\n", 
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

    // Release the Mutex.
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

So as you can see Main does not call mut.WaitOne(-1) if it had called it like I DO in my example it means that the thread running main would have to call ReleaseMutex 2 times instead of just one.

You can be wondering, what?! But how can the thread call 2 times WaitOne, are you mad, actually this is very interesting, because since the thread calling Main initially owns the Mutex, it would have to ReleaseMutex also 2 times, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
If a thread owns a Mutex, that thread can specify the same Mutex in repeated wait-request calls 
without blocking its execution; however, it must release the Mutex as many times to release 
ownership.
```

And that's it,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is a *very* serious threading bug, you cannot ignore it.  Your code is calling Enter() but not Leave().  Which gets you a mutex that is acquired but will never be released, a guaranteed recipe for deadlock.

Luckily, .NET can detect the mishap, the thread that owns the mutex stopped running which automatically means it is never going to call ReleaseMutex().  That's always bad, so it raises the exception to help you realize that your code has a deadlock bug.  At the very minimum, you need a hard guarantee that ReleaseMutex() is always called, even if there's an exception:

```
Kitchen kit = new Kitchen();
kit.Enter();
try {
    kit.DoCooking();
}
finally {
    kit.Leave();
}
```

Albeit that the code looks too fake to be actually usable as-is.

Comment: The question had a bug, Close should had been Leave. And the code is usable Hans, imagine you need to lock on something and release it later on, and I guarantee to you that Leave is called. Try to compile the example in VS and run it... That exception will pop up... Don't know why, I waitone and then I release...

Comment: You only get that guarantee for the *lock* keyword.  Not for Mutex.  The *lock* keyword in your code does nothing useful, WaitOne and ReleaseMutex are already thread-safe.  And no, your snippet doesn't compile and when it is fixed then it doesn't reproduce the exception.  Another question bug?

Comment: The lock is used do access a shared variable inside the Kitchen class, I omitted that for the sake of simplicity. Anyway it's not the try catch that gives that guarantee because the DoCooking it's empty no code inside... so the Release is called always. Have you tried to simulate this?